# angular: how to config the service independently for different modules?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

In the same app I have 2 modules: `module1` and `module2`.

I am trying to integrate `angular-translate` to have have independent vocabularies for each module.

> For such purpose I'm using `custom loader service`.

I insert `$translateProvider.useLoader('some service loader name')` into config section(for each module). There are two different custom loaders in each module with **unique names**. But it seems for me that there is only one translate service instance through all the application.

I'm not sure is it right. If so and I am able to have only one service instance in the moment (how) is it possible to configure service independently for each `module`?

Comment: modules aren't isolated in the app...all components are available throughout the app. Need more details about what you are trying to do and some configuration code

Comment: my app contains two modules that can be used at the same time(say first is configurator and second one is a viewer) or separately. It's structured as two independent modules: directive + set of controllers/views. 

I'm trying to integrate angular-translate into each of this modules independently. Something like http://pastebin.com/VWZLUZMA

Comment: So here I waited for independent angular-translate's instances. But as I see provider has already been configured in second module's config function.

PS sorry I am still unfamiliar with SO's commenting feature. A lot of unintentional savings :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Angular 1.x definitely instantiates services only once per life cycle(https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)
So there is no chances to create several instances and to initialize them independently.
As far as I know it's changed in Angular 2.x